# Converting UTF-8 with C++ standard libraries (no /clr)

Tags: c++, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a string like this: "These are Pi (\u03a0) and Sigma (\u03a3).". How can i convert this to contain and print effective characters, using C++ standard libraries?

This solution http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8(VS.80).aspx, use .NET framework (/clr compiling), that i want to avoid preferring C++ standard libraries.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you mean by "standard", but I guess you meant "unmanaged". If that's what you want, please try [ICU](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/). It is not very easy to master, but it is definitely capable of such [conversions](http://userguide.icu-project.org/conversion).

BTW. If you simply want to convert UTF-16 encoded wstring to UTF-8 encoded string, you can do it with [WideCharToMultiByte()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call (assuming Windows).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do this using the standard library, altough my guess would be that there isn't. You could however use [iconv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv). It's part of gnus standard C library, but there's a [windows dll available](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/iconv-1.9.2.win32.zip).